# Latest news mini images

Tags: posts, images, post-thumbnails, previews

I tried to find an answer on websites and other forums, but found nothing. I will try to explain my problem.
I need to change my WordPress website so that it displays a small image for all news articles, that is in the "latest news" on the main page. I'm using headway theme editor if that is important.

upd:
As was requested in the comments, here is [my website](http://vungtau-city.com).

Comment: Maybe [this](http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Thumbnails) can get you started...

Comment: Can you post a link to what you're working with? Might be easier to give an answer if you provide an example.

Comment: I've updated the question.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned above, this link can help you on your way:
http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Thumbnails

You need to add thumnail sizes to your functions.php like:

```
the_post_thumbnail();                  // without parameter -> Thumbnail
the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail');       // Thumbnail (default 150px x 150px max)
the_post_thumbnail('medium');          // Medium resolution (default 300px x 300px max)
the_post_thumbnail('large');           // Large resolution (default 640px x 640px max)
the_post_thumbnail('full');            // Original image resolution (unmodified)
the_post_thumbnail( array(100,100) );  // Other resolutions
```

Then in your theme template within the loop where you call your image (for example loop.php), you need to change your image code into:

```
<?php if(has_post_thumbnail()) { the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail');  ?> // which will get you an image of 150x150
```

Comment: I'm far from all the pogramming stuff... maybe there is a way to do it without changing code?

Comment: Can anybody help?